# how to include the preceding 0 for an integer input in C++

Tags: c++

I am VERY new to C++, so I don't really know exactly what I am doing wrong, I do have a limited knowledge in java, buts that's it.

I am currently working on a program which asks the user to input a year (i.e. 2007) and the program takes the 2 numbers in that year (in this case 20 and o7) then it adds 1 to the first 2 digits (so 21) then it displays them again as a year which will be 100 years ahead of the year they inputed.

My problem is when I input 2007 or 1206 or any number with a 0 as the 3rd digit, the result is 217 (for the 2007 case). I was wondering if there was a way to make sure that the output includes all numbers of the year.

Here is my program so far:

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <cstdlib>
 #include <string>
 #include <iomanip> 

 using namespace std;

 int main()
 {
 cout.precision(4);
 cout << setfill('0') << setw(2) << x ;
 //declaring variables
 int year;
 int firstDigits;
 int secondDigits;
 int newFirstDigits;
 int newSecondDigits;
 int newYear;
 //gets the year from the user
 cout <<"please enter a year in YYYY format"<<endl;
 cin>>year;
 //finds the dirst 2 digits
 firstDigits=year/100;

 //finds the second 2 digits 
 secondDigits=year%100;

 //adds 100 years to the year that was inputted
 newFirstDigits=firstDigits+1;

 newSecondDigits=year-firstDigits*100;
 //outputs to the user what 100 years 
 //from the year they entered would be
 cout<<"the new year is "<<newFirstDigits<< newSecondDigits<<endl; 

 system ("PAUSE");

 }
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: perhaps take your input as a string?

Comment: Why not just add 100 to the entire year? Otherwise you need to read in the second part as a string to retain a preceding 0 (or use a zero fill, but this is much more complicated than what is needed for this).

Comment: thanks for all the replies... in the end I ended up adding 100 to the year and that seemed to work out. thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Use [`std::setw(int width)`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setw/) from `<iomanip>`.

You use it all the way up-top:

```
 cout << setfill('0') << setw(2) << x ;
```

But that will only set it when printing `x`. When printing to `cout` in the future, the IO manipulations are lost. What you'll want to do is:

```
 cout << "the new year is "
      << setfill('0') << setw(2) << newFirstDigits
      << setfill('0') << setw(2) << newSecondDigits << endl;
```